Putnam 2008 B2 -- Soft Question
The 2008 Putnam exam has the following question for B2:
Let $F_0(x) = \ln x.$ For $n \geq 0$ and $x>0,$ let $F_{n+1} (x) = \int _0 ^xF_n(t) \, dt$. Evaluate $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n! F_n (1)}{\ln (n)}$$

In order to solve it, one must prove that $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{H_n}{\ln n} = 1$ where $H_n = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + \cdots + 1/n$ (the $n$th harmonic number). It's a pretty well known result that $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} H_n - \ln n = \gamma \approx 0.577.$$
Would one be allowed to use this result in the actual Putnam exam? Or would it be considered "trivializing the problem" and therefore cause a point deduction?

I don't know how Putnam reviewers grade, but you could prove that yourself by an integral comparison and then you should be safe.

Did you take a look at the solution? If they explicitly proved in the solution that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{H_n}{\ln(n)} = 1$, and that appears to be the crux of the solution, then there is your answer--no you are probably NOT allowed to assume this result.

I would expect some kind of integral estimate as well

Alright yeah, I figured you could easily prove that $0<\gamma <1$, which would probably be the safer route. The thing is that it's not the "crux" of the solution per se, but it's definitely a significant portion. Thanks!

I really do not know what the judges would do. It isn't so hard to prove the result in question directly though. In particular, observe the string of inequalities
$$\frac{1}{n+1} \quad \le \quad \int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{1}{t} dt$$
$$\le \frac{1}{n}.$$ So
$$\sum_{n=2}^{k+1} \frac{1}{n} \quad = \quad H_{k+1} -1$$
$$\quad \le  \quad \int_{1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{t} dt \quad = \quad \ln(k)$$
$$\le \quad \sum_{n=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \quad = \quad H_k.$$
This, as the inequality $H_k \le$ $H_{k+1}$ is true, shows that $|H_k - \ln(k)|$ is no more than $1$.
